# How can you run into DEADLOCKS without LOCKS?

Tags: php, laravel, transactions

In have a class in my Laravel app which goes over a set of users and updates them within a [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions) but without [lock](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#pessimistic-locking).

The code looks roughly like this:

```
DB::transaction(function () {

    // ...
    foreach($groupOfUsers as $user){
         Car::where('user_id','=', $user->id)->update(['color' => 'red');
    }
})
```

Now I used [Paratest](https://github.com/paratestphp/paratest/tree/2.2.0) which runs multiple processes for my integration test for the above class. All process use the same database.
Everytime, one of my tests fails for the above class fails with a DEADLOCK. But I don't understand how this is possible. I thought deadlock can only occur if I actually lock rows for update or use share lock.

How can you create a DEADLOCK with updates only?

Comment: its possible during writing process even using transaction, when using multi-process, same row will be used by different process at the same-time, while the row is being in-process by third-process, the two others will wait each other and deadlock occurs.

Comment: @Akam are you saying if I have a website that only does `UPDATE name="bob" WHERE id=1` on a request, then this can create a deadlock if too many concurrent requests occur?

Comment: In real cases, this will not happen, why one row or some rows will be updated at same time many times? MySQl recommends to minimize number of rows in each transaction so that the rows will be released for other process.

Answer (score -1):

without foreach just

```
DB::transaction(function () {

    // ...
         Car::where('user_id','=', $user->id)->update(['color' => 'red');
})
```